# About Higher Order Fourier Analysis

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

This quastion is about the **extension of Fourier analysis to higher orders**. I know this is the approach *to go beyond the linear phases*. I am curious to understand it better. To be specific,

1. Is it possible to briefly explain the higher order Fourier analysis with giving some clear *mathematical representation* of that analysis (just like the traditional form)?
2. Would you please provide some *applications* of the higher order Forier analysis?

Thanks.

Comment: What is "higher order Fourier transform" ?

Comment: @reuns: Please look at: https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/higher-book.pdf I also edted the question.

Comment: Are you expecting people to read a 200-page book in order to understand what your question is about?

Comment: @Rahul: 1. I don't  expect anything. 2. I thought, may be somebody has enough knowledge about it beforehand. 3. There are other resources one can find easily https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.2260.pdf.

Comment: What do you get with the change of variable $\xi = y^2$ in the inverse Fourier transform integral ? If you are just told to study that field we can't help. If you want to understand or generalize a concrete application we can.